# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple, in a minimal Django application

Tags: python, django

I'm building an application with Django. Whenever I try using `os.path.join()` in the `'DIRS'` list of the `TEMPLATES` setting I get `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple`.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),

# Settings
settings.configure(
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ],
    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ],
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [
                os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), # Here
            ],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ],
    STATIC_URL = '/static/',
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), # ...and HERE!
    ],
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534731/typeerror-expected-str-bytes-or-os-pathlike-object-not-tuple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `,` from `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),` otherwise it will read it as a tuple,

so that it must be:

`BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`

Comment: This is the new error - `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple`

Comment: remove `,` from `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),`

Comment: Just to note, the first part of the answer is wrong, only the latter part is necessary.